# How to address "The parameters 'tags' are missing or invalid:" error while running my runner class using maven command "mvn test"?

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, maven-plugin, cucumber-junit

I am getting this error when I am trying to run the runner class by using **`mvn test`** command:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.temyers:cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin:5.0.0:generateRunners (generateRunners) on project Demo_Automation: Invalid parameter. : Invalid parameter.

[ERROR] The parameters 'tags' are missing or invalid: [null]
```

I kept both my runner class and stepdefinitions in same folder:

```
src/test/java/setpfiles/runnerclass.java & stepdefinitionfiles
```

I added the required plugins and dependencies in my pom file but still facing the error.

These are the plugins in pom.xml

```
'<plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generateRunners</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            
                            <glue>
                                <package>aaa_stepFiles</package>
                            </glue>
                            
                            <outputDirectory>src/test/java/aaa_testcases</outputDirectory>
                            
                            <featuresDirectory>src/test/resources/aaa_FeatureFiles</featuresDirectory>
                            
                            <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber-parallel</cucumberOutputDir>

                            
                            <plugins>
                                <plugin>
                                    <name>json</name>
                                    <extension>json</extension>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-parallel/json</outputDirectory>
                                </plugin>
                            </plugins>

                        
                            <strict>true</strict>
                            
                            <monochrome>true</monochrome>
                            
                            <tags>
                                
                                <tag>${Scenario}</tag>
                            </tags>
                            
                            <useTestNG>false</useTestNG>
                            
                            <namingScheme>simple</namingScheme>
                            
                            <namingPattern>Parallel{c}Test</namingPattern>
                            
                            <parallelScheme>SCENARIO</parallelScheme>
                            
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
        
            

        </plugins>
        
    </build>'
```

Comment: Show your runner class

Comment: import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
plugin = {"pretty"},
features = "src/test/resources/aaa_FeatureFiles/Home.feature",
glue= {"HomePageStepDefinitions.java"})
//tags = "src/test/resources/tbs_FeatureFiles")
public class RunnerClass {

}

Comment: Show how you set up your `cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin` in `pom.xml`

Comment: @AlexeyR. attached the part which you asked in the summary. please check

Comment: What Cucumber version do you use? I have two guesses. 1) You are using Cucumber v >=4.0. It has native support so plugin author mentions that plugin was no tested with v 4. So there is kind of incompatibility. 2) You use `${Scenario}` in your tag. Probably it goes empty.

Comment: @AlexeyR. I tried by changing the tag like <tag>@tagname</tag>. No the error gone. but it is not taking the stepfiles.

Comment: What about cucumber version

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that both the files:

- *runnerclass.java*
- *stepdefinitionfiles*

both are within *`/src/test.java`*

---

Additionally, within `@CucumberOptions` pass the location of the feature file as follows:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/AppFeatures/Order.feature"},
        glue = {"stepdefinations"},
        plugin = {"pretty"}
        )
```

Comment: Yes both the files are inside the java folder only. and location of the feature file also i gave . still getting the same error.
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
plugin = {"pretty"},
features = "src/test/resources/aaa_FeatureFiles/Home.feature",
glue= {"HomePageStepDefinitions.java"})
//tags = "src/test/resources/aaa_FeatureFiles")
public class RunnerClass {

}